# SQL Server query to split a string and then convert a part a part into column name and other its value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, my boss has given me a string and asked me to split it and convert as following.

Sample data:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Put all the relevant information in the question.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (how to ask a good question).

Comment: Use split function to return string as rows and then use pivot to show as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any straight forward answer.

- First `split` the column values into rows
- Next apply `conditional aggregate` or `Pivot` operator to get the
  result

Try something like this

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT str,
       rn,
       replace(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'=','.') split_value
FROM   (SELECT row_number()over(order by str) as rn,
                str ,
               Cast ('<M>' + Replace(str, '@', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data

        from test) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) 
), split as
(
select rn,str,parsename(split_value,2) as col_name,parsename(split_value,1)  as row_val
from cte 
)
select str, 
max(case when col_name  = '6ss' then row_val else '' end) as [6ss],
max(case when col_name  = '6mm' then row_val else '' end) as [6mm],
max(case when col_name  = '8mm' then row_val else '' end) as [8mm],
max(case when col_name  = '12mm' then row_val else '' end) as [12mm],
max(case when col_name  = '16mm' then row_val else '' end) as [16mm],
max(case when col_name  = '10mm' then row_val else '' end) as [10mm]
from split
group by str,rn
```

- [**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/127ab/3)

There are N numbers of methods to *split string* in `sql server` check this [**link**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) with performance comparison

Comment: Thanks you so much,i have got the result from above query.

Comment: But there is one problem it is not showing 10mm value.

Comment: you wrote 1Omm i have replaced 1Omm with 10mm, but still not showing value?

Comment: replace here `CASE WHEN col_name = '10mm' THEN row_val ELSE '' END` and in Input string

Comment: @Tariq - Updated check now. Check the demo

Comment: @Tariq - Dont forget to accept it as answer. It will be helpful for future readers

Comment: Can you please suggest me a good book for mssql where i can learn how to make query easily